# How to write this mysql query

Tags: mysql

### Table Structure

```
id | term | result
==================
1  | t1   | 0
2  | t2   | 0
3  | t1   | 34
4  | t1   | 23
5  | t2   | 10
6  | t2   | 10
7  | t3   | 20
```

The table is for a search table where term is the keyword someone was searching for, and result is the number of results returned at that time. Now from this table I need to retrieve 
1) number of times a term was searched for and 
2) the number of results that were returned when it was last search for.

for the first one I can do `count(term) group by term`, and for 2 probably `ORDER by id DESC`, but I don't know how to do both in a single query. Any help?

Comment: How do you recognise the order in which searches took place?  Does a greater `id` imply a more recent search?

Comment: hims056 - the two queries I wrote above, but as I said, I have no idea how to do that together as GROUP BY will return the first record in the group

@eggyal - Yes, MAX(id) is most recent search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT term, count, result
FROM   my_table NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT term, COUNT(*) count, MAX(id) id FROM my_table GROUP BY term
       ) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8304/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT() function to aggregate the result fields, and then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get back the one you want.

`SELECT COUNT(term), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(result ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) FROM table GROUP BY term`

Answer (score 1):

```
   select term, count(*), (select result from my_table where id = max(t.id)) 
   from my_table t 
   group by term
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8516/1)

Answer (score -1):

Use following query

```
      select id,term,count(*) as 'count',result from (select * from table33 
 order by id desc) as abc group by term
```

Comment: [The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: @eggyal try to run above query

Comment: The values chosen are *indeterminate*.  Just because it happens to yield correct results at the current time does not mean that one can rely on it doing so in the future.

Comment: @eggyal its always working for me.. i am first sorting table in the descending order of id then i am grouping by term. That means you will get value with 
max id

Comment: No, it doesn't.  ***THE VALUES CHOSEN ARE INDETERMINATE***.  The MySQL developers could not be more explicit on this point.  You really shouldn't rely on this behaviour.